# Creating POJOs in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, pojo

I am trying to create pojo's. My requirement is to retrieve user information based on policy id. Each customer has only one address and one policy.

So I have created three POJO's. Address.java, Customer.java, Policy.java.

Address.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CUSTOMER_ADDRESS")
public class Address {


    @Column(name="ADDRESS_STREET")
    private String address_street;

    @Column(name="ADDRESS_CITY")
    private String address_city;

    @Column(name="ADDRESS_STATE")
    private String address_state;

    @Column(name="ADDRESS_ZIPCODE")
    private String address_zipcode;

    @GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "foreign",
    parameters = @Parameter(name = "property", value = "CUSTOMER"))
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
    @Column(name="CUSTOMER_ID")
    private int customer_id;
    public String getAddress_street() {
        return address_street;
    }
    public void setAddress_street(String address_street) {
        this.address_street = address_street;
    }
    public String getAddress_city() {
        return address_city;
    }
    public void setAddress_city(String address_city) {
        this.address_city = address_city;
    }
    public String getAddress_state() {
        return address_state;
    }
    public void setAddress_state(String address_state) {
        this.address_state = address_state;
    }
    public String getAddress_zipcode() {
        return address_zipcode;
    }
    public void setAddress_zipcode(String address_zipcode) {
        this.address_zipcode = address_zipcode;
    }
    public int getCustomer_id() {
        return customer_id;
    }
    public void setCustomer_id(int customer_id) {
        this.customer_id = customer_id;
    }



}
```

Customer.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CUSTOMER")
public class Customer {

    private int customer_id;
    private String customer_name;
    private Date customer_dob;
    private Address address;
    private Policy policy;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "CUSTOMER_ID")
    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "CUSTOMER_ID")
    public Policy getPolicy() {
        return policy;
    }
    public void setPolicy(Policy policy) {
        this.policy = policy;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "CUSTOMER_ID")
    public int getCustomer_id() {
        return customer_id;
    }
    public void setCustomer_id(int customer_id) {
        this.customer_id = customer_id;
    }

    @Column(name = "CUSTOMER_NAME")
    public String getCustomer_name() {
        return customer_name;
    }
    public void setCustomer_name(String customer_name) {
        this.customer_name = customer_name;
    }

    @Column(name = "CUSTOMER_DOB")
    public Date getCustomer_dob() {
        return customer_dob;
    }
    public void setCustomer_dob(Date customer_dob) {
        this.customer_dob = customer_dob;
    }

}
```

Policy.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CUSTOMER_POLICY_DETAILS")
public class Policy implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="POLICY_ID")
    int policy_id;

    @Column(name="POLICY_START_DATE")
    String policyStartDate;

    @Column(name="POLICY_END_DATE")
    String policyEndDate;

    @GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "foreign",
    parameters = @Parameter(name = "property", value = "CUSTOMER"))
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
    @Column(name="CUSTOMER_ID")
    int customer_id;

    public int getCustomer_id() {
        return customer_id;
    }

    public void setCustomer_id(int customer_id) {
        this.customer_id = customer_id;
    }

    public Policy() {
        super();
    }

    public int getPolicy_id() {
        return policy_id;
    }



    public void setPolicy_id(int policy_id) {
        this.policy_id = policy_id;
    }



    public String getPolicyStartDate() {
        return policyStartDate;
    }

    public void setPolicyStartDate(String policyStartDate) {
        this.policyStartDate = policyStartDate;
    }

    public String getPolicyEndDate() {
        return policyEndDate;
    }

    public void setPolicyEndDate(String policyEndDate) {
        this.policyEndDate = policyEndDate;
    }


}
```

Should I include the Address object and Policy object in my Customer class?
Since I have the customer_id attribute in the Address and Policy class, do I not need to include it in my Customer class?

Answer (score 0):

i understood from your description .the relation between Customer and Address is one to one and Customer must has address and address belong to one Customer and for policy too .so it deosn't matter whether Customer  in Address or Address in Customer pojo .

so in your case you will get customer object then Address and policy from same object.i hope to answer your question .

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Including **address** and **policy** entities in customer entity is one of the simple ways to pull up the customer information based on *policy_id* and *address_id*. To achieve this, you need to include primary keys of **address** and **policy** entities in **customer** entity. Based on the code that you provided, join column for address entity must be *Address_id* and join column for policy entity must be *policy_id*.

1. You have given same name for two of your mapping in **customer**
   entity. Since these mapping represents relationship and foreign
   keys, name of the primary key columns of respective entities must be
   your join columns.
2. Since you have only *one-one* mapping to other entities bidirectional
       mapping not imposing any problems here. But you should be very
       careful about bidirectional mapping in other relationship mappings.